# Using Google gapi browser library on react native

Tags: react-native, google-api

My app successfully logs users into Google using `react-native-google-signin`. I want to call other google APIs like the Google Calendar API using a token.

Which of the 3 options (or something else entirely) should I use?

1. Download the javascript file from [google-api-javascript-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) and put it in my project. The tutorials for that are for html pages rather than react native. They suggest using **script tags** in the HTML.
2. Use the [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) which adds [4mB](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=googleapis@49.0.0)
3. Make requests manually using axios/ fetch (this is what **I did** in the end)